# Unable to install VS code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I had installed VS code on one of my drives (G:) but after installing I changed the drive letter to (E:)
so the pah was broken but now I am unable to install vs code again it's throwing this error

[image]

What I have tried,

1. Removing VS code data under Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Code
2. Removing VC code from Path Variable

Comment: Easiest solution would be to temporarily assign letter `G:` to the same drive, uninstall VS Code, unassign `G:`, then do a fresh install on `E:`.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, I had installed other stuff so had second thoughts about doing that. But it helped. It's fixed now.